# Android User Interface Like Unlock Pattern Android

Tags: android, user-interface, user-input, custom-view

I want to make a something like a draw/game application to practice with the user interaction.

but I want it to work and look like the android's security "unlock pattern". I mean I want to draw the circles and when the user interacts with them by either drawing a line or maybe just marking the circles..  but that is the main idea.

I've been trying to find out how to make it happen but I jut can't find it.

I think would be creating a custom view adding the circles and so on but now sure if this is correct. Maybe with Drawable ? I've tryied with buttons but seance I want to press it one and don't release the screen the onClick event is not being fired.

as well if is a custom view I do can use it withing a Fragment right?

If you can point me in the right direction would be great, I've searched for examples that make something like this but I couldn't found any, so If you can point me to one example I'll be thankful or confirm that creating a Custom View is the way to go and why would that be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the pattern unlock, you can find the [choose lock pattern here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/settings/ChooseLockPattern.java/) from the dev docs.

If you're looking for the new slider style unlock (ICS), you can find some info regarding that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807047/algorithm-of-the-joystick-on-the-touchable-screen).

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer it does helps me on how can I do this,  still a little advanced for me.. I'll study the code and try to solve it from there. I'll mark it as correct answer if I can get the view from it.

Comment: thanks a lot you definetelly put me in the right direction after checking a little deeper the code What end up helping me a lot is the class LockPatternView that extend view and does kind of the same of what I needed.